# how to join two or more different regex and match values in flutter dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, match

Am trying to match an email address and mobile number using regex and I want it to check if if matches an email, mobile number or both in a single string

**Number regex:** this matches mobile number for my country

```
Pattern pattern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{11,}$)';
RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
```

**Email regex:** this is the regex for matching email address which works for me

```
Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
```

And if this is the string I want to match it to `String sentence = "My email example@gmail.com and my mobile number is 09056783431`  please how do I do it. If you need more explanation please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
final numberRegex = new RegExp(r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{11,}$)');

if(numberRegex.hasMatch(myMobileNumber)) print ('True')
else print ('Mobile number format is incorrect')
```

And do the same thing with Email

Comment: ok thanks but what about if am trying to replace the match string with another value like using `replaceAllMapped`

Comment: Have a look at https://www.codevscolor.com/dart-replace-substring-in-string